# A problem on logarithm

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Can this expression (see below) be written in the form $g_kw^{h_k}$. Where $g_k$ and $h_k$ are functions of only $k$?:
$(1- k)^{\lceil\log_kw\rceil - 1}$. Here $k$ and $w$ are positive integers.

I can get an upper bound:
let $(1- k)^{\lceil\log_kw\rceil - 1} \leq (1- k)^{\log_kw} = w^a$ and take $\log_k$ on both sides, $\log_kw \log_k(k-1)= a\log_kw$, giving, $a = \log_k(k-1)$

Comment: Any (positive) $f(k)$ can be written as $1\cdot w^{\log_w f(k)}$.

Comment: @Berci I think you mean $\log_w$. But, that makes $h_k$ (using the OP's notation) dependent on $w$ as well as $k$; he wants $h_k$ to be dependent only on $k$.